# File path with users username (c#)

Tags: c#, path

I'm trying to make a button in c# which creates a folder in the users Roblox directory. I thought this would be an easy job, until I realised that I can't simply put my username in C:\Users\*users username.

This is my current code:

```
string clntSett = 
"C:\\Users\\*users username*\\AppData\\Local\\Roblox\\Versions\\version-40b6a27c6c4d46ef\\ClientSettings";
            if (!Directory.Exists(clntSett))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(clntSett);
            }
```

What should I replace the "users username" part with to make it work with all the people who use it?
By the way, I am new to c# so feel free to give me any suggestions/corrections with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=net-7.0) method to get the path of the local application data folder, then use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-7.0#system-io-path-combine(system-string-system-string)) method to combine it with the subpath.

```
var localAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
var clntSett = Path.Combine(localAppData,
                "Roblox\\Versions\\version-40b6a27c6c4d46ef\\ClientSettings");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Environment.GetFolder()` to get a lot of special folders.

Try the following to get part of the path. (Use `Path.Combine()` to append additional subfolders.)

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```